# Custom Markup Extension default value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a custom markup extension that returns a boolean or a Visibility depending on the attribute it's used in.

It compares the level provided as parameter to the current user level

Now, the system is working when I'm using it :

```
<Button Visibility="{u:RestrictTo User}" IsEnabled="{u:RestrictTo Manager}" />
```

But IntelliSense is telling me that there is two errors :

'' is not a valid value for property 'Visibility'.

'' is not a valid value for property 'IsEnabled'.

In case this is revelant here is my implementation of the RestrictTo markup extension :

```
public class RestrictTo : MarkupExtension
{
    public UserLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }

    public RestrictTo() { }

    public RestrictTo(object accessLevelStr)
    {
        AccessLevel = (UserLevel) Enum.Parse(typeof(UserLevel), accessLevelStr.ToString());
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var valueService = (IProvideValueTarget) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
        if (valueService == null)
            return null;


        var property = valueService.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
        if (property == null)
            return null;


        var target = valueService.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (target == null)
            return null;


        var userManager = Application.Current.Resources["UserManager"] as UserManager;
        if (userManager == null)
            return null;


        var binding = new Binding()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("UserLevel"),
            Source = userManager,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Converter = new UserLevelToAccessConverter() { AccessLevel = this.AccessLevel }
        };


        return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }

}
```

And the converter :

```
public class UserLevelToAccessConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public UserLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        UserLevel userLevel = (UserLevel) Enum.Parse(typeof(UserLevel), value.ToString());

        if(targetType == typeof(bool))
            return userLevel >= AccessLevel;

        if (targetType == typeof (Visibility))
            return (userLevel >= AccessLevel) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;

        throw new ArgumentException("UserLevel can only be converted to a bool or a visibility");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the constructor, the string passed as an argument is parsed to an `Enum` of type `UserLevel`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> But IntelliSense is telling me that there is two errors

I'm assuming you use the visual designer.

**Solution**: Don't use the visual designer.

Two options:

1. Disable it: Tools → Options → XAML designer → uncheck "Enable XAML Designer"
2. Change editor: Right click XAML file → Something like "Open with" → Select "Source code editor" → Set as default

Comment: Well I'm using the "Xaml" tab not the "Design" one but still there is IntelliSense errors

Comment: @LionelPire: They are linked, any errors created by the design view show up in the XAML view. First thing i do when i have a new VS install is setting the default editor to the text editor for XAML files.

Comment: Disabling the designer seems to have removed those errors, could you edit your answer to add the steps to do so so I can validate your answer?

On VS2015 : Tools -> Options -> Xaml designer -> uncheck "Enable XAML Designer"

Comment: @LionelPire: Added both options.

Comment: This does not really solve anything.